# ASP.Net core web API controller Scaffolding failed - The connection could not be established

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-scaffolding

In Visual Studio 16.4.4, in a ASP.Net Core 3.1.1 Web API project using Entity Framework Core, when I try to scaffold a new controller of any kind, I get the following error :

> Scaffolding failed. The connection could not be established because the target computer expressly refused it. [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:55226

I don't know exactly when the problem began. I think it was when a firewall window appeared and I unintentionally closed it. But I didn't have time to see if I clicked Allow or Deny. Unable to find the possible firewall rule that would have been added...

Any suggestion for restoring scaffolding functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because my VPN was running, disabling it solved the problem.

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't solve the problem for me. Note uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio does...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the windows firewall, and see if the scaffolding functions come back to life, if it does, turn on your firewall and delete all firewall rules and wait it to prompt for permission again

Comment: Hi Giovani. Even with firewall disabled, the scaffolding still does not work.